# Switching Visual Studio to C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

trying to get my first windows form running with controls. I havent been able to figure anything out. . . and then i realized duh, it's all in VB. How do I switch the generated files to C#? Am I confused? This is what I'm getting when I try to add my first control for Button_Start:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Click_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button_Start.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

**Wow that was silly. I didn't realize there were multiple versions. Thanks!**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a C# Winforms project, not a VB Winforms project. If you're not using a full version of Visual Studio, but an Express version, then you need to download the C# Express version, and not use the VB Express version.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your project is currently a VB.NET WinForms project.

If you would like to convert your VB.NET code to C#, try an online code converter. There are lots out there, but perhaps try [CarlosAG's code converter](http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/CodeTranslator/).

Simply add a new C# WinForms project to your solution, and copy/paste as needed!